# Write mdat of mpeg-4 into mpeg-ts using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mp4, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

If I have an mp4 file with incomplete ftyp and moov but a valid mdat, can I write mdat frames into mpeg-ts? Do I really need to get sps and pps if I do not plan to decode/encode? Shouldn't it simply read/write frames from input stream into output stream?

Comment: if you're not planning on decoding or encoding, then you don't need anything. can you try and explain what this mpeg-ts is for then? there are many ways in general to converting from mpeg4 to mpegt2s - but you need the h264 headers, and you need PES headers.

Comment: @NiRR I'm writing out Android's mp4 into socket in order to try and stream it while its recording. Because seek is not supported by socket's FD, I do not get a valid FTYP and MOV atoms (nor can i wait for them to be formed and I want to try and stream as close to real time as possible). I want to pack MDAT frames into .ts because it supports data streams as well as being streamable. I can get SPS and PPS info by doing a dummy recording, producing a short mp4, and extracting info prior to starting my stream. Hence, I want to know if MDAT can be packed into .ts file with the above info known.

Comment: recording the mdat will produce an elementary stream (if you'll be capturing both audio and video mdats then you'll have both elementary streams). mpeg ts is a packetized format that wraps an elementary stream, so if you want the output to be a compliant mpeg ts you have more work to do: this is called multiplexing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream)